# how to attach debuggger to already running jvm with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jvm

If I run a Spring project in Eclipse, I can either hit run or debug. Is it possible to start debugging the application while it is already running without restarting it? I know for sure that Intellij Ide can do it with android JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, if you debug or run the server when it is running, if you click run it will rerun or debug it will be run in debug mode. Yo can see it on button run and debug when server is running.

For debug

> Restart the server in debug mode

For Run

> Restart the server